# カウントアップアプリが起動しない

Tags: flutter

Android StudioでFlutterの新規プロジェクトを作成し、作成したプロジェクト直下の lib/main.dartを実行すると下記のエラーが出て、[+]ボタンをクリックすると数値が増えていくカウントアップアプリがエミュレータに表示されないで困っています。

**やってみたこと**
Android Device ManagerでActions->Wipe Dataは、試してみました。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
cmd: Can't find service: activity
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\StudioProjects\i_am_rich\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
Error launching application on AOSP on IA Emulator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Deviceを削除して、新しいVirtual DeviceでRunしたら動いた。

[image: カウントアプリ]